# Scala.Byte vs java.lang.Byte -Which one is recomended to use?

Tags: java, scala

I was wondering which of the two possibilities is preferred. In my opinion they do more or less the same. 
What are the reasons why there are two implementation?
Are there differences in the performance or functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `scala.Byte` in most cases, because it corresponds to *both* `byte` and `java.lang.Byte` in Java terms and you usually want `byte`. The compiler will use `byte` for `scala.Byte` where it's possible/makes sense.

Comment: Using scala.Byte future proofs your code for use in Scala.js and Scala Native (and future Scala Webassembly) where reliance on the JVM implementation details is less desirable.

Comment: @chaotic3quilibrium They both support significant part of Java standard library, including `java.lang`: https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js/blob/master/javalanglib/src/main/scala/java/lang, https://github.com/scala-native/scala-native/tree/master/javalib/src/main/scala/java/lang. Too much Scala code (including the Scala standard library!) relies on it to make anything else feasible.

Comment: While I agree with you in Scala 2.x and 3.x, I predict that Scala 4 will be the move to become independent of the JVM dependencies. It is inevitable as Scala becomes more opinionated, it will also become more focused on being retargetable beyond the JVM constraints.

Answer (score 3):

> In my opinion they do more or less the same.

It's quite the same. Scala compiler compiles to Java bytecode, just like the Java compiler also compiles to JVM bytecode. A `scala.Byte` will therefore result in the same bytecode as the usage of `java.lang.Byte`.

> What are the reasons why there are two implementation?

"Scala runs on the JVM, so Java and Scala stacks can be freely mixed for totally seamless integration." This is how Scala is described on https://www.scala-lang.org/. So there are not really two implementations within Scala. You are just provided with the ability to use things from Java if you like / have to.

> Are there differences in the performance or functionality

As mentioned above, you can consider them on byte code level as equal. However, they are at least diffrent in usage. If you write your Scala code like you would in Java, you can expect the same performance.

> Which one is recomended to use?

If you can, use the Scala implementation. Simply because you'll not leave the "Scala world" and therefore benefit from potential improvements made by the language.

Comment: This is a little inaccurate. A `java.lang.Byte` is a _wrapper_ for the _Java_ `byte` primitive, in cases where an object is required—but it cannot be used a primitive itself and has overhead associated with its use. In _Scala_, a `scala.Byte` can be viewed as both a primitive (in many cases, the _Scala_ compiler will optimize instances to use `byte` primitives in outputted _bytecode_) _and_ as an object. So `scala.Byte` is definitely preferred in _Scala_ code.

Comment: Also, this is not true: "Scala compiler compiles to Java bytecode, just like the Java compiler also compiles to JVM bytecode". There are *some* Scala compilers which compile to JVM byte code, but e.g. Scala.js compiles to ECMAScript source code, Scala-native compiles to native machine code, and the (abandoned) Scala.NET compiled to CLI CIL byte code.